# Setting UITextView backgroundColor to clearColor makes it animate - how to prevent this?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am adding a UITextView to a UIView programatically. The UITextView should have a clear background from the get go,  but the background is animating from white to clear. How do I prevent this animation? Here is my code:

```
UITextView *localTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 60)];
localTextView.opaque = NO;
localTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
localTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
localTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.textView = localTextView;  
[localTextView release];

textView.text = @"Cras sit amet purus vitae libero venenatis luctus sit amet non urna. Curabitur volutpat adipis cing nulla, in lacinia eros pulvinar vitae.";

[self addSubview:textView];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the animated change in backgroundColor based on the code you have supplied.  Are you doing this in a UIView or UIViewController class?  How long does the color change animation last?  Are you creating an animation block using UIView beginAnimations:context: anywhere?

Comment: It lasts about one second. I think it might be related to the off-screen refresh issue of UITextView? I found this mentioned near the bottom of the page  here http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html in an excellent post by  Matt Gallagher. I am using the UITextView in offscreen views in a UIScrollView. The thing I don't understand is... the view that is onscreen (the first page in the scrollview) does it too. I'm mystified.

Comment: I'm using the UITextView inside a custom view that extends UIView. The view is loaded into a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up your view in the

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL*)animated;
```

method

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very old post, but I had the same issue after pushing programmatically a `UIViewController` with an `UITextView` as it's main view onto a `UINavigationController` stack.

I solved this in Swift 2.2 with iOS 8+ API like this:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```